# Bash /usr/bin/time command runs command in subshell

Tags: bash, time

In a bash script (running on REHL5) I use the /usr/bin/time command (not the builtin time command) to record the run times of other commands I run in that same script. The problem I am facing is that some of the commands that I want to record times for are not builtin commands or external scripts but are functions that are either declared in the script or are sourced from a different script. I have found out that the time command fails with error like below:

`/usr/bin/time: cannot run shared-func: No such file or directory`

Which means that the function shared-func() that I declare elsewhere is not visible in the scope and therefore time cannot run that command. I have run some tests and have verified that the reason behind this error is in fact because the time command tries to execute its command in a new subshell and therefore loses every declared function or variable in its scope. Is there a way to get around this? The ideal solution would be to force the time command to change its behavior and use the current shell for executing its command but I am also interested in any other solutions if that is not possible.

For the record, below is the test I ran. I created two small scripts:

**shared.sh:**

```
function shared-func() {
    echo "The shared function is visible."
}
```

**test.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

function record-timestamp() {
    /usr/bin/time -f % -a -o timestamps.csv "$@"
}

source "shared.sh"
record-timestamp shared-func
```

And this is the test:

```
$ ./test.sh
/usr/bin/time: cannot run shared-func: No such file or directory
$
```

Comment: Stop using the external time command? External binaries cannot just re-use the current shell they don't know anything about its context and cannot interact with it.

Comment: By the way -- `shared-func` isn't a valid function name in POSIX sh. Current versions of bash will let you get away with it if you use the `function` keyword, but that behavior isn't documented, so it could go away in future versions without notice. Much safer to stick to POSIX function definitions.

Comment: What would be the POSIX standard way?

Comment: @exbuddha, the POSIX form declaring functions is `shared_func() { ...; }`, with no `function` keyword preceding. To be clear, by the way -- bash does document the `function` keyword, so though I still don't advise it (for making scripts gratuitously POSIX-incompatible) that's not going away any time soon. It's the support for dashes in function names, only supported when that keyword is used, that's more questionable.

Comment: (postscript to people reading this eight years later: bash now allows dashes in function names even without the `function` keyword used).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different *process*, yes. A *subshell*, no.

A subshell is what you get when your parent shell forks but doesn't `exec()` -- it's a new process made by copying your current shell instance. Functions are accessible within subshells, though they can't have direct effect on the parent shell (changes to process state die with the subshell when it exits).

When you launch an external program without using `exec`, the shell first forks, but then calls `execve()` to invoke the new program. `execve()` replaces the process image in memory with the program being run -- so it's not the `fork()`, that is, the creation of the subshell causing this to fail; instead, it's the `exec()`, the invocation of a separate program.

Even if your new process is also a shell, if it's gone through any `exec()`-family call it's not a subshell -- it's a whole new process.

---

**tl;dr**: You cannot use an external program to wrap a shell function invocation inside the current shell, because an external program's invocation always uses `execve()`, and `execve()` always clears process state -- including non-exported shell functions.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the correction. So, I don't have any options it looks like other than using a different command other than /usr/bin/time.

Comment: Pretty much. There are workarounds -- you could export a function to the environment, and invoke it in a new shell, for instance -- but they have ugly side effects; in that specific one, you'd need to also export all dependencies, and the new shell couldn't modify state of its parent, plus the timing would include all the overhead of spinning up the child process.

Answer (score 0):

```
function shared-func() {
    echo "The shared function is visible."
}

export -f shared-func

echo shared-func | /usr/bin/time -lp /bin/bash
```

Output:

```
cat <<EOF
The shared function is visible.
real 0.00
user 0.00
sys 0.00
             1040384  maximum resident set size

...
```

---

On a 3GHz machine, the overhead of running bash this way is approximately 5ms (u+s time).

Comment: _nod_. As I mentioned in a 2014 comment on the older answer, that _works_, but (1) for any complex function, one would also need to export variables/other functions/etc it depends on; (2) the function won't have identical behavior with respect to any side effects on the process it was invoked from (variables that would be set, directories changed, etc don't happen); and (3) the timing includes not just the function's execution but all the work of spinning up a new copy of bash to run it in, so it's going to be considerably more expensive running it in-process.

Comment: Some limitations are timeless....

Answer (score 0):

`/bin/time` is a separate program so it will be run in a separate process, and then it will try to run yet another program in yet another separate process.

There's a trick though, a shell script can call itself, or in this case tell `/bin/time` to call itself.

```
function record-timestamp() {
    /usr/bin/time -f % -a -o timestamps.csv bash "$0" "$@"
}

if [ -n "$1" ]; then
    source "shared.sh"
    "$@"
else
    record-timestamp shared-func
fi
```

If you call `test.sh` with arguments then it will try to run that function (which comes from `shared.sh`), and if you call it without arguments will call the `record-timestamp` function which in turn will call `/bin/tine` which in turn will call `test.sh` with arguments.